# NgRx Redux devtools not showing store and state details even though applicaton is working fine

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx, redux-devtools-extension

I am using the below sample application to learn angular+ngrx.
[APM Sample NgRx App](https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-NgRx-GettingStarted/tree/master/APM-Demo1)

I have installed Redux firefox extension. But whenever I run/reload application, redux tab shows 'No store found' message. The application is working as expected(is able to retain state). I am able to dispatch actions, handle it in the reducer etc..
Please help.. I am stuck in this for quite a long time.

Comment: Both chrome and firefox extensions show 'pin: undefined' on launching the redux devtools

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To use the Redux devtools you'll have to install @ngrx/store-devtools and import it in the `AppModule` - [docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/store-devtools).

Install it with:

```
npm install @ngrx/store-devtools --save
```

Import it with:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
    // Instrumentation must be imported after importing StoreModule (config is optional)
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 25, // Retains last 25 states
      logOnly: environment.production, // Restrict extension to log-only mode
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: It's important to note that the order of the imports is important. `StoreDevtoolsModule` must be loaded after `StoreModule`.

Answer (score 39):

There is an issue with Angular app when `Redux` doesn't see your `Store`

Check that you have

```js
StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({maxAge: 25, logOnly: environment.production})
```

**after**

```js
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers)
```

Otherwise you are in trouble.

**BTW, it is better to install DevTools with**

```sh
ng add @ngrx/store-devtools
```

It adds schematics to the project.

Comment: This option work for me and you save my effort of days. Thank you

Comment: Thank you a lot. I just put the store dev tool above the StoreModule.forRoot. Silly me

Comment: @TonyNgo my problem also was the order of the store module and store devtools module , your comment helped me

Answer (score 0):

If you have @ngrx/store-devtools installed and the store still doesn't show up (instead, you see **No store found - *blah blah blah* instructions**), context menu over the frame and select **Reload Frame**.

One of the tickets claimed that this workaround should no longer be necessary, but to me it was (Angular and store around v.7.2.x, Redux DevTools extension 2.17)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the ngrx/store-devtools by following commands

```
npm install @ngrx/store-devtools --save
```

> I want to put my two-cent experience that might be helpful for many of you. There is an order issue. You have to the add ngrx/store-devtools after the reducer. If you do not maintain the order, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

call instrument method in-app module to resolve this error.

Example-

```
 imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        // StoreModule.forRoot({}),
        // StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }),
    
        StoreModule.forRoot({ count: counterReducer }),
    
        // for debugging enable this instrument in development mode
        **!environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument() : [],**
    
        CustomerModule
    
      ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... Then finally I tried running my app outside of VSCode debugger, and everything works fine. Somehow the debugger in VSCode doesn't allow you to see the Redux tab in Devtools